# Update table with top 1 field from other table

Tags: sql

I've been fighting this for a few days.  I have an inventory table based on a barcode field. I also have a location table that has multiple entries as this item may have been moved multiple times.  I want to add a current_location field in the inventory table that shows the location the item was moved to last.  So, I want the location_to field from the location table with the most recent date_modified. I can't quite get my head around this.

So the inventory table has (only one entry per barcode):

```
barcode=xxx current_location = null
barcode=yyy current_location = null
```

The location table has (multiple entries per barcode):

```
barcode = xxx, location_to = 1, datemodified = 01/01/2022
barcode = xxx, location_to = 2, datemodified = 01/02/2022
barcode = xxx, location_to = 3, datemodified = 01/03/2022
barcode = yyy, location_to = 4, datemodified = 01/04/2022
barcode = yyy, location_to = 5, datemodified = 01/05/2022
barcode = yyy, location_to = 6, datemodified = 01/06/2022
```

I want to set the inventory.current_location = 3 for xxx and 6 for yyy as those are the most recent via datemodified.

I have tried something like this:

```
update Inventory
set current_location = 
L.location_to 
from Inventory I
inner join Location L on I.Barcode = L.Barcode
where L.DateModified = (select top 1 L.DateModified where I.Barcode = L.Barcode order by L.DateModified DESC)
```

But this returns the same current_location for xxx as for yyy as the top one is not specified per barcode.

I hope this makes some sense as my brain is fried and I can't quite get my head around it. I hope the initial description of the problem is enough because I think the code I am attempting is wrong and is just confusing the entire issue.

Thank you for looking at this.  I know some of you will see this as an easy problem and once I see the solution, I probably will as well.

Comment: Please TAG your DBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with your query, not least your subquery is missing `from location`. From your use of `top 1` you're probably using SQL Server.

You could perform the update using a CTE such as:

```
with i as (
    select i.current_location, l.Location_to
    from Inventory i
    cross apply (
        select top (1) l.Location_to
        from location l
        where l.Barcode = i.Barcode 
        order by l.DateModified desc
    )l
)
update i set current_location = Location_to;
```

Comment: I like the promise of this but :  Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 78
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. I can't see where this conversion is occurring.

Comment: @SteveCross that's my bad I put the wrong column name in by mistake, have amended, can you review again?

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward is a subselect with subselect, working with every DBMS:

```
UPDATE Inventory i SET current_location = (
      SELECT l1.location_to from Location l1
       WHERE l1.barcode = i.barcode and 
             l1.datemodified = (SELECT max(l2.datemodified) from Location l2
                                 WHERE l2.barcode = i.barcode))
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6hL7qXV8HtPC9ChrsrP4Mj/0)

Comment: it is SQL and I'm getting an Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 61
Incorrect syntax near 'i'. I don't think it likes the definition there.

Comment: @SteveCross Had a type in the field, added a running db fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, since you've put TOP 1 in there, then this should work:

```
UPDATE Inventory
SET current_location = L.location_to 
FROM Inventory I
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT Barcode, location_to, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Barcode ORDER BY DateModified DESC) AS rownum 
            FROM [Location]
            ) L on I.Barcode = L.Barcode
WHERE L.rownum = 1;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening here.  I checked a barcode and the current_location is not listed for that barcode in location. However, every current_location in the table is set to the same current_location.

Comment: Please edit your post to show exactly what code you ran and a table showing the results of the update.

Comment: If you can also add a create/insert statement for sample data for each table, we will be able to test more easily. Thanks

Comment: Thank you but Turo's solution did the trick. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Stu's query, but if you wanted to "fix" your query, this should work.

Notice adding `location` as `L2` in the `DateModified` subquery.

```
update Inventory
set current_location = 
L.location_to 
from Inventory I
inner join Location L on I.Barcode = L.Barcode
where L.DateModified = (select top 1 L2.DateModified from [location] L2 where I.Barcode = L.Barcode order by L2.DateModified DESC)
```